# QMessageBox avoid auto linebreaks

Tags: qt, messagebox, line-breaks

Is there a way to restrict linebreaks in the text of a QMessageBox to where a `<br>` occurs? I.e. no auto-linebreaks anywhere else? Something like `msgBox.setAutoLinebreaks(False)` would be nice...

Comment: A Message box should probably break on lines when the text reaches the end of the box, if they don't, they will overflow outside of the box. Docs says that "The text will be interpreted as a plain text.", IE, `<br>` should be printed as "<br>", and your own breaks should probably be "\n" instead of "<br>".

Comment: The `textFormat` is set to AutoText by default and though interprets `<br>` as linebreaks (should not be mixed with `\n`!). That works fine, but the width of the `QMessageBox` should be adjustable or is this fixed anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want, you may use this dirty hack to do it:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
QString loremIpsum = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.";
loremIpsum.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
msgBox.setText(loremIpsum);
msgBox.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
msgBox.exec();
```

But the size of the message box is still limited by some internal logic, so it simply won't display the rest of the line if it doesn't fit. On my system this is truncated at “ab ill”. Note that auto-breaking algorithm might break not only at spaces (not sure about that), so you may have to use non-breaking hyphens or something more. I wouldn't dare to use this as a generic solution, but it could be used for a specific case.